# Locate LaTeX source code for page style

Tags: pagestyle

I am trying to locate the page style handling code in LaTeX. In my implementation the
base folder has 126 files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: almost all of the format source is `latex.ltx` but that is stripped of comments, you may prefer `texdoc sourc2e`  then look up `\pagesyle` in the index.  line13351 of `latex.ltx` is`\def\pagestyle#1{%`

Comment: Sometimes things like \ps@empty are defined in the cls files.